# How to fetch multiple images using Sentinel-Hub's EO Browser Custom script?

Tags: sentinel-1, sentinel-hub

I'd like to use the floods Sentinel-hub Playground custom script in EO Browser so that I may download the result as geoTiff. https://github.com/sentinel-hub/custom-scripts/tree/master/sentinel-1/flood_mapping#

The Playground script compares two S1-GRD VV images at different points in time and returns the difference.

Bringing it into EO Browser's Custom script area gives the error:
An error has occurred while fetching images:
Dataset with id: 0 not found.

There is a checkbox named "[X] Use additional datasets (advanced)" where you can select "S1GRD" as a source, which I'd expect would allow me to fetch additional images but I still get the error.

Is it possible to use multitemporal data in EO Browser's custom scripts?

Answer (score 0):

It was simple - in the "Visualize" area of EO browser there is a new toggle option "Timespan" where you can set the date range for the images in your custom script

I was helped by reading this
https://medium.com/sentinel-hub/new-themes-multi-temporal-scripting-and-other-improvements-in-eo-browser-725267d09f2f